# FullCalendar and multiple events using function

Tags: codeigniter, fullcalendar

I am looking to use FullCalendar with CodeIgniter. Here's what I am trying to do:

JS File:

```
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventSources: getSources()
    });
```

View File:

```
<script>
    function getSources()
    {
        [
            <?php
                $output = '';
                foreach (explode(",", $session) as $session_id) { 
                $output .= " { url: '/campaigns/current_sessions/".$session_id."' },";
            } 
            echo rtrim($output, ',');
            echo "\n";
            ?>

        ]
    }
</script>
```

JSON Output

```
[{"name":"Second Session","start":"2013-04-7T00:00:00Z","end":"2013-04-3T00:00:00Z"}]
```

The URLs are taken fine. I checked the output of the json data, it's in correct format too. Is there any problem with my function call to getSources? Is there any other way I can add multiple sources dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

i made a simple php file to handle xml and return the xml formatted in a way that full calendar understand and you can put the php script in the libraries folder in codeigniter or in any folder you want inside the Aplication folder (your choice). Also i fetch the events dynamically with jquery ajax.

In the php file i handle ajax requests for example the select:

This is to fetch events from a xml file:

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myxml.xml',
                dataType: 'xml',
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
                },
                success: function(doc) {
                    var events = [];
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {
                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),
                            allDay: $(this).attr('allDay'),
                            editable: $(this).attr('editable')
                        });                             
                    });                                     
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        } 
});
```

This is the select: (FullCalender) function to insert/save an event:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay){           
                var name = prompt('Title for event:');                  
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',                           
                        url: 'myxml.php',                           
                        data: {'id': 9999,
                                'ajax':true,
                                'operation':'add',
                                'title':name,
                                'start':start,
                                'end':end,
                                'allDay': allDay,
                                'editable': true, 
                                },                                      
                        success: function(data) {           
                            //alert('SUCCESS');
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');                                 
                        }
                    });             

        }
```

This is the PHP file that handles the request to insert and to save to the xml file, notice that this is not prepared to "multiple access". Also i didn't manage to delete an event in this script i stopped there, no time. Anyway you can understand the logic and adapt to your specific problem. I hope i helped ;). Here's the script:

```
<?php

//error detection
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 if($_POST['ajax']){
$operation = $_POST['operation'];
    $eventid = $_POST['id'];    
    $eventattributes = array('id'=> $eventid,
                            'title'=>$_POST['title'],
                            'start'=> $_POST['start'],
                            'end'=> $_POST['end'],
                            'allDay'=>$_POST['allDay'],
                                'editable'=>$_POST['editable'],
                              //'backgroundColor'=>$_POST['backgroundColor'],
                              //'borderColor'=>$_POST['borderColor'],
                              //'textColor'=>$_POST['textColor']
                            );  
        if(file_exists('myxml.xml'))
        {       
            $filepath = realpath('myxml.xml');                          
            if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file($filepath)){
            trigger_error('Erro a ler XML',E_USER_ERROR);
        }           
            switch($operation)
                    {
                        case 'edit':{ editXML($xml,$eventid,$eventattributes,$filepath); break;}
                        case 'add':{ $newID = getLastEventID_XML($xml); 
                                     addXML($xml,$filepath,$eventattributes,$newID); break;}
                        case 'remove':{ removeXML($xml,$eventid,$filepath); break;}                         
                        default: {echo 'Operação não  reconhecida!'; break;}                            
                    }       
         }else{         
             exit('Failed to open myxml.xml');
         }      
          }else{
         exit('Nothing to be done!');
          }
         function editXML($xml,$eventid,$eventattributes,$filepath)
               {        
        foreach($xml->events->event as $event)
                    {
        if ($event['id'] == $eventid)
            {
                $event['title'] = $eventattributes['title'];
                $event['start'] = $eventattributes['start'];
                $event['end'] = $eventattributes['end'];
                $event['allDay'] = $eventattributes['allDay'];
                $event['editable'] =    $eventattributes['editable'];                   
            //  $event['backgroundColor'] =   $eventattributes['backgroundColor'];
            //  $event['borderColor'] =  $eventattributes['borderColor'];
            //  $event['textColor'] =  $eventattributes['textColor'];           
                break;
            }           
    }   
    file_put_contents($filepath, $xml->asXml());
}

function addXML($xml,$filepath,$eventattributes,$newID)
{   
    $event = $xml->events->addChild('event');
    $event->addAttribute('id',$newID);
    $event->addAttribute('title',$eventattributes['title']);
    $event->addAttribute('start',$eventattributes['start']);
    $event->addAttribute('end',$eventattributes['end']);
    $event->addAttribute('allDay',$eventattributes['allDay']);
    $event->addAttribute('editable',$eventattributes['editable']);  
    //var_dump($eventattributes);
    file_put_contents($filepath, $xml->asXml());
}


function removeXML($xml,$eventid,$filepath)
{       
    //TODO remove event
}

function getLastEventID_XML($xml)
{
    $id = 0;
    $innercount = 0;
    $count = $xml->events->event->count();  
        foreach($xml->events->event as $event)
            {
                //var_dump($count);
                //var_dump($event['id']);                   
                $innercount++;          
                //var_dump($innercount);
                if ($count === $innercount)
                    {
                        $id = $event['id'];                         
                    }else{
                        $id = 0; 
                    }                                   
            }
    //var_dump($id);
    //echo $id; 
    $id = (int)$id + 1;
    return $id;
}

function getChildNodePosition($xml,$eventid){
    $position = 0;
    $innercount = 0;
    //$count = $xml->events->event->count();    
        foreach($xml->events->event as $event)
            {                                       
                $innercount++;                      
                if ($event['id'] == $eventid)
                    {
                        $position = $innercount;                        
                    }                                   
            }   
return $position;
}   
?>
```

Comment: We moved away from it finally as it didn't fit into our new design. So, I haven't tested for the correct answer. Thanks for the help.